# How to replace Softmax ouput Layer with Logistic Layer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, logistic-regression, softmax

I need a bit help in my work. Right now, I am using Softmax layer as output layer for classification scores in neural network. But, I need to replace Softmax layer with logistic layer on the output layer. I have some inputs that belongs to multiple classes. Softmax is showing probability over all the classes and assigned the class to the highest probability and its hard to decide a threshold to predict more than one classes at a time. While in case of logistic function each neuron will display a number between (0-1) and I can decide a threshold in that case.
Here is my code:

**2 layer Network Initialization**

```
# Parameters
training_epochs = 10#100
batch_size = 64
display_step = 1
batch = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
regualarization =  0.009

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 250 # 1st layer num features
n_hidden_2 = 250 # 2nd layer num features

n_input = model.layer1_size # Vector input (sentence shape: 30*10) 
n_classes = 12 # Sentence Category detection total classes (0-11 categories)

#History storing variables for plots
loss_history = []
train_acc_history = []
val_acc_history = []


# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

#Strings
trainingString = "\n\nTraining Accuracy and Confusion Matrix:"
validationString = "\n\nValidation set Accuracy and Confusion Matrix:"
testString = "\n\nTest set Accuracy and Confusion Matrix:"
goldString = "\n\nGold set Accuracy and Confusion Matrix:"

# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(_X, _weights, _biases):
    #Single Layer
    #layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(_X, _weights['h1']), _biases['b1'])) 
    #return tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    ##2 layer
    #Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(_X, _weights['h1']), _biases['b1'])) 
    #Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, _weights['h2']), _biases['b2'])) 
    return tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']  

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    ##1 Layer
    #'h1': w2v_utils.weight_variable(n_input, n_hidden_1),
    #'out': w2v_utils.weight_variable(n_hidden_1, n_classes)

    ##2 Layer
    'h1':  w2v_utils.weight_variable(n_input, n_hidden_1),
    'h2':  w2v_utils.weight_variable(n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2),
    'out': w2v_utils.weight_variable(n_hidden_2, n_classes)   
}

biases = {
    ##1 Layer
    #'b1': w2v_utils.bias_variable([n_hidden_1]),
    #'out': w2v_utils.bias_variable([n_classes])  

    ##2 Layer
    'b1': w2v_utils.bias_variable([n_hidden_1]),
    'b2': w2v_utils.bias_variable([n_hidden_2]),
    'out': w2v_utils.bias_variable([n_classes])
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
#learning rate
# Optimizer: set up a variable that's incremented once per batch and
# controls the learning rate decay.
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
    0.02*0.01,                # Base learning rate.
    batch * batch_size,  # Current index into the dataset.
    X_train.shape[0],    # Decay step.
    0.96,                # Decay rate.
    staircase=True)

#L2 regularization
l2_loss = tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in tf.trainable_variables()])

#Softmax loss
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y)) 

#Total_cost
cost = cost+ (regualarization*0.5*l2_loss)

# Adam Optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost,global_step=batch)

 # Initializing the variables
 init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

 print "Network Initialized!"
```

How we can modify this network to have a probability in between (0-1) on each output Neuron?

Comment: I am confused. So the difference is you sent each probability to sigmoid and then pick a threshold, instead of thresholding on probability directly?

Comment: Right now, I am getting softmax probabilities. But, I want sigmoidal layer so each neuron will return a probability from 0-1. Softmax is returning a probability distribution over all classes and highest will be selected as a label for input. But, I have multiple labels and I need a threshold to figure out those. In case of sigmoidal I will clearly set a threshold for example above 0.5 all classes will belongs the input? Doest it make sense?

Comment: My understanding is you get a distribution from which you take argmax for classification. I see that you want to relax the problem definition so that you get multiple positive classes. One way is just to rank the output and pick top N, if you don't like arbitrary thresholding. it also matters how your distribution looks like. If your output consistently gives two 0.4 and others 0.0X (or any multimodal-like), then pick the top group or threshold at 0.2. If you pass them through sigmoid, you would do the same thing afterward, but they don't have to add to 1, which is harder to interpret.

Comment: Use `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead of `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` during training, and pas your `pred` variable through `sigmoid` during inference

Comment: Yaroslav results are not good and it seems it is predicting only one class :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change line:

```
# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
```

To

```
# Construct model
model pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases))
```